# Faster way to do `A[tuple(B.T)]` in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have a M by N array `I`, each row of which is an index an N dimensional array `A`. I want a vectorized expression to get the 1-d array of the M indexed values from A. I found that `A[tuple(I.T)]` does the right thing, but profiling shows it to be very expensive despite being vectorized. It is also not particularly elegant or "natural" and `A[I]` and `A[I.T]` do something completely different

What is the right way to do this?
It should also works for assignment like

```
A[tuple(I.T)] = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are talking about something like:

```
In [398]: A=np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
In [401]: I=np.array([[0,1],[1,2],[3,4],[0,0],[2,5]])

In [402]: tuple(I.T)
Out[402]: (array([0, 1, 3, 0, 2]), array([1, 2, 4, 0, 5]))

In [403]: A[tuple(I.T)]
Out[403]: array([ 1,  8, 22,  0, 17])
```

This is http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing - purely integer array advanced indexing.

This is always going to be slower than basic indexing, which returns a view.  Basic indexing pickes contiguous blocks of data, or values that can be selected with strides.  That isn't possible with your indexing.

Look at some timings:

```
In [404]: timeit tuple(I.T)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.4 µs per loop

In [405]: timeit A[tuple(I.T)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10 µs per loop

In [406]: %%timeit i,j=tuple(I.T)
   .....: A[i,j]
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.86 µs per loop
```

Constructing the tuple takes about 1/3 of the time.  `i,j=I.T` is just a bit faster.  But that indexing is the largest piece.

`A[i,j]` is the same as `A[(i,j)]` (as is `A.__getitem__((i,j))`).  So wrapping `I.T` in `tuple` just produces the 2 indexing arrays, one for each dimension.

It is faster to index on a flattened version of the array:

```
In [420]: J= np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(I.T),A.shape)
In [421]: J
Out[421]: array([ 1,  8, 22,  0, 17], dtype=int32)

In [422]: A.flat[J]
Out[422]: array([ 1,  8, 22,  0, 17])

In [425]: timeit A.flat[J]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 µs per loop

In [426]: %%timeit
    .....: J= np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(I.T),A.shape)
    .....: A.flat[J]
    .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 µs per loop
```

So being able to precompute and reuse the indexes will save you time, but there's no way of getting about fact that selecting a bunch of individual values from `A` will takes extra time.

Just for fun, compare the time it takes to index `A` with each row of `I`:

```
In [442]: timeit np.array([A[tuple(i)] for i in I])
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.3 µs per loop
In [443]: timeit np.array([A[i,j] for i,j in I])
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.7 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) another way, like so -

```
def ravel_einsum(A,I):

    # Get A's shape and calculate cummulative dimensions based on it
    shp = np.asarray(A.shape)
    cumdims = np.append(1,shp[::-1][:-1].cumprod())[::-1]

    # Use linear indexing of A to extract elements from A corresponding 
    # to linear indexing of it with I
    return A.ravel()[np.einsum('ij,j->i',I,cumdims)]
```

**Runtime tests**

Case #1:

```
In [84]: # Inputs
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,5,2,4,5,2,6,8,2,5,3,4,3))
    ...: I = np.mod(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,A.ndim)),A.shape)
    ...: 

In [85]: %timeit A[tuple(I.T)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.7 µs per loop

In [86]: %timeit ravel_einsum(A,I)
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.3 µs per loop
```

Case #2:

```
In [87]: # Inputs
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,5,4,2))
    ...: I = np.mod(np.random.randint(0,5,(10000,A.ndim)),A.shape)
    ...: 

In [88]: %timeit A[tuple(I.T)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 357 µs per loop

In [89]: %timeit ravel_einsum(A,I)
1000 loops, best of 3: 240 µs per loop
```

Case #3:

```
In [90]: # Inputs
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,10,(30,50,40,20))
    ...: I = np.mod(np.random.randint(0,50,(5000,A.ndim)),A.shape)
    ...: 

In [91]: %timeit A[tuple(I.T)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 220 µs per loop

In [92]: %timeit ravel_einsum(A,I)
10000 loops, best of 3: 168 µs per loop
```